# Magento 2 afterRender ko binding loses customer scope

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have a custom block rendered in header which displays the customer's available credit limit.

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <div class="store-credit-limit" data-bind="style: { display: customer().is_staff > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }, afterRender: function(){jQuery('body').addClass(customer().customer_group_class);}">
       <div class="store-credit-limit-inner">
            <span class="credit-label" data-bind="i18n: 'Available Credit Limit :'"></span>
            <span class="credit-value" data-bind="text: '$' + customer().credit"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After rendering this DOM I want to add a specific class to the body which is set in customer object as `customer().customer_group_class`. The problem here is the class does not get added. However, if I use the text binding, the class is displayed in that section. 
Why is customer object undefined in afterRender binding?